# Infinite size file when decrypting (Python)

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to make a program where I can store passwords, the part of the program that stores and prints passwords is working fine, but I tried to add a password to be able to run the program. Since I want that password to be persistent across multiple runs of the program I created a file where the password is stored, and before showing any passwords, I have to put that password. The problem is that, since I don't want someone to be able to open the password file with a text editor to see the password, I tried encrypting it, but when I try to decrypt the file to check if the user input is the same as the password, the program freezes (it still allows input but doesn't do anything) and the text file keeps increasing in size, when I noticed the first time (about 30 seconds since the IDE froze) the file was 8gb and I had to force close Python to be able to delete the text file.

```
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto import Random
opcionCorrecta=False
repetir=True
sesiónIniciada=False
def encrypt(key, filename):
  chunksize = 64*1024
  outputFile = filename
  filesize=str(os.path.getsize(filename)).zfill(16)
  IV = Random.new().read(16)

  encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

  with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
      outfile.write(filesize.encode('utf-8'))
      outfile.write(IV)

      while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

        if len(chunk)==0:
          break
        elif len(chunk) % 16 !=0:
          chunk += b' ' *(16-(len(chunk)%16))

        outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
def decrypt(key, filename):
  chunksize = 64*1024
  outputFile = filename[:11]

  with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    filesize = int(infile.read(16))
    IV = infile.read(16)

    decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)

    with open(outputFile, 'wb') as outfile:
      while True:
        chunk = infile.read(chunksize)

        if len(chunk)==0:
          break

        outfile.write(decryptor.decrypt(chunk))
      outfile.truncate(filesize)
def getKey(password):
  hasher = SHA256.new(password.encode('utf-8'))
  return hasher.digest()
#Bucle para repetir el programa hasta que se elija la opción para salir
while repetir:
    while sesiónIniciada==False:
        if os.path.isfile("E:\Mis Documentos\Python\contraseña")==False:
            contraseña=input("Introduce la contraseña para tu cuenta: ")
            contraseñaArchivo=open("contraseña","w")
            contraseñaArchivo.write(contraseña)
            encrypt(getKey(contraseña), "contraseña")
            contraseñaArchivo.close()
        elif os.path.isfile("E:\Mis Documentos\Python\contraseña"):
            contraseña=input("Introduce tu contraseña: ")
            decrypt(getKey(contraseña), "contraseña")
            contraseñaArchivo=open("contraseña","r")
            if contraseña!=contraseñaArchivo.read():
                print("Contraseña incorrecta")
                sesiónIniciada=False
            else:
                print("Contraseña correcta")
                sesiónIniciada=True
            contraseñaArchivo.close()
    #Bucle para asegurarse que se elije una opción válida
    while opcionCorrecta==False:
        if os.path.isfile("E:\Mis Documentos\Python\cuenta"):
            print('''Elige una opción:
                1. Introducir cuenta
                2. Buscar cuenta
                3. Mostrar todas las cuentas
                4. Salir''')
            opción=int(input())
            if opción<1 or opción>4:
                opcionCorrecta=False
            else:
                opcionCorrecta=True
        else:
            print('''Elige una opción:
                1. Introducir cuenta''')
            opción=int(input())
            if opción!=1:
                opcionCorrecta=False
            else:
                opcionCorrecta=True
    if opción==1:
        #El programa pide la página, el usuario y la contraseña y después los añade a un archivo separando los datos con comas
        Pagina=input("Introduce el nombre de la página: ")
        Usuario=input("Introduce el nombre de usuario: ")
        Contraseña=input("Introduce la contraseña: ")
        cuenta=open("cuenta","a")
        cuenta.write("%s," % Pagina)
        cuenta.write("%s," % Usuario)
        cuenta.write(Contraseña)
        cuenta.write("\n")
        cuenta.close()
        opcionCorrecta=False
    if opción==2:
        #El programa pide la palabra a buscar e imprime todas las líneas que incluyan la búsqueda
        búsqueda=input("Introduce tu búsqueda: ")
        with open("cuenta") as f:
            for line in f:
                if búsqueda in line:
                    print (line)
                    opcionCorrecta=False
    if opción==3:
        #Imprime todos las cuentas guardadas en el archivo
        cuenta=open("cuenta","r")
        print(cuenta.read())
        opcionCorrecta=False
    if opción==4:
        #Cierra el programa
        repetir==False
        break
```

For making the encryptor/decryptor I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqjdXMu4ZAQ) tutorial

Comment: Your script is not indented properly.  Cutting and pasting into a script to try it gives an indentation error.

Comment: I think that may be because of the 4 spaces used to format the question, I don't get any indentation errors when running it myself

Comment: Still, fix it. Notice the lack of answers.  In python indentation is important, and only you know what is correct. Take your working script, make sure it is indented properly without tabs, cut and paste it here, and format it with the `{}` button.

Comment: The formatting should be fixed now